# Delay in ng-show hiding elements when condition is false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm rather new to AngularJS and am having this issue happening throughout my app.  When I use `ng-show` (or even `ng-hide`), when the condition is false, there's a delay in the element hiding.  It's a good 1 sec delay.

**One instance:**
So if there is not a subdomain description, the button is meant to hide...immediately.

```
<button
    class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right animated fadeIn"
    title="Show Domain Info"
    ng-click="hideMe = !hideMe"
    ng-show="vm.subdomainDescription"
>
  <img src="assets/images/icon_info_circle.svg" class="icon-md" alt="Info">
</button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the JS code that happens on click (tab change)

Comment: How is vm created/modified in the click? Are there and changes if you don't use animations?

Comment: The `ng-click` is just a toggle to show/hide the domain description.  It's just a view-only function – not a controller function.  Nothing is being created or modified in the click.  Even if I remove the `ng-click` there's still the same issue with the delay.

Comment: Even with no animated there's still a delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.  I have a transition on all the buttons like so:

```
.btn {
  position: relative;
  @extend .gotham-medium;
  border: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  @include transition(background-color $transition-settings);
}
```

I was also using animate.css classes `animated fadeIn`.  When those classes where removed the problem persisted because I also have the transitions on the button. It was a combination of both. It was a combination of both.

That was the culprit.  What a knob I am :)